# Error writing file in Openshift Origin

Tags: java, apache-camel, openshift

I'm deploying a camel based application to Openshift Origin.
The camel route requires to write some pdf files to the file system.
So I created a Persistent Volume Claim and then created the storage for the Pod that has the camel route. The mount references a valid directory and that directory is writable from other users besides root.

The PV is succesfully added to the pod because I ran

```
oc volume pod/sat-pdf-merger-7-64s9v
```

And I Got

```
pods/sat-pdf-merger-7-64s9v
  pvc/volume0 (allocated 100GiB) as volume-efwkb
    mounted at /recibos/pdf
  secret/default-token-r45zl as default-token-r45zl
    mounted at /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
```

It is important to say that the same project works fine on Jboss Fuse 6.3. So the exception is thrown because of some Origin issue, not a related camel or java code problem.

When the route executes, the following exception throws:

```
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Error writing file [ComprobanteNomina00000001401.pdf]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.writeFile(GenericFileProducer.java:279)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.processExchange(GenericFileProducer.java:165)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileProducer.process(RemoteFileProducer.java:58)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor$1.doInAsyncProducer(SendDynamicProcessor.java:124)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:436)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor.process(SendDynamicProcessor.java:119)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.WireTapProcessor$1.call(WireTapProcessor.java:137)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.WireTapProcessor$1.call(WireTapProcessor.java:133)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

EDIT

I upload here the results from debugging the POD.

[image]

My Dockerfile

```
FROM 172.30.1.1:5000/myproject/fis-java-openshift:2.0
ENV JAVA_APP_DIR=/deployments
USER root   
RUN mkdir -p /home/jboss/recibos
RUN chmod -R 777 /home/jboss/recibos
COPY maven /deployments/
EXPOSE 8080 8778 9779
```

When debuging the pod, I saw that the mkdir in the dockerfile actually did not work. So I need some workaround.

Comment: Do you have some way of confirming that when it is writing ``ComprobanteNomina00000001401.pdf`` that it is actually using a full path name that would fall in ``/recibos/pdf``? The error isn't showing a full path, so it may be writing to the current working directory of the process, which may not be a writable directory.

Comment: Yep. In the code I'm trying to write the file to /recibos/pdf

Comment: Can you ``oc rsh`` into the container and run ``df /recibos/pdf`` and ``ls -las /recibos/pdf`` and ``date > /recibos/pdf/date.txt`` and include the output in your question. Also, what sort of OpenShift installation is this? Are you using Minishift, or have you installed OpenShift yourself from scratch?

Comment: OK, I edited the question. I'm using Openshift origin v.3.7.1. Btw, I changed the code to just use /recibos/ instead of /recibos/pdf

Comment: Which suggests you have no volume mounted. What does ``df`` alone in the container show? What do you get for ``oc describe`` on the deployment configuration, especially, what do you get for ``Volumes`` and then ``Mounts`` for each container?

Comment: Also perhaps read the chapter of free eBook https://www.openshift.com/promotions/deploying-to-openshift.html about persistent volumes and see if they helps as far as ensuring you are claiming and attaching the volume correctly.

Comment: I detected that the error comes from camel's FTP component. The pdf files are wrtitten to 2 locations: one is FTP, the other is e-mail via SMTP. Yesterday I sent some emails with the pdf attachment, but for FTP, it remains in excepcion (I think this is a bug). I'm trying other librarys instead of camel's FTP.